# lpic package error: image file not found, even though includegraphics finds it with no problems

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to use the [lpic package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lpic) to superimpose text on images (makes labelling with correct font sizes easier), but it cannot find my image file.

I've seen plenty of questions about `\includegraphics` not finding image files and the file database having to be refreshed, but `\includegraphics` finds the same image fine. I've tried to move image files around as I thought perhaps lpic was having trouble with my subfolder for images, but that didn't help either.

Why can't lpic find my image? I'm using TeXlive on Mac.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%for images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lpic}          %LaTeX text on pictures 

\begin{document}
    Some text
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig.png} %works fine

            \caption{Caption text.}
        \end{figure}

        Some more text ...

        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \begin{lpic}[l(0mm),r(0mm),t(0mm),b(0mm),draft]{fig.png} %does not work
                \lbl[l,W]{20,50;Label text at 20,50 position}
            \end{lpic}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try {fig} instead of {fig.png}.

Answer (score 3):

For very strange reasons, `lpic` uses the deprecated and obsolete syntax of `epsfig`, which is a package that should never be used in new documents and is available just for back compatibility.

Fix the command that uses the bad syntax:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%for images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lpic}          %LaTeX text on pictures
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% Fix \lp@dimens to use \includegraphics rather than \epsfig
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lp@dimens}
  {\epsfig{figure=\lp@epsfile}}
  {\includegraphics{\lp@epsfile}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\lp@dimens}
  {\epsfig{figure=\lp@epsfile, width=\lp@tmpx, height=\lp@tmpy}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\lp@tmpx,height=\lp@tmpy]{\lp@epsfile}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{osum.png} %works fine
  \caption{Caption text.}
\end{figure}

Some more text ...

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{lpic}[l(0mm),r(0mm),t(0mm),b(0mm),draft]{osum.png} %does not work
  \lbl[l,W]{20,50;Label text at 20,50 position}
  \end{lpic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]